# Wordpress Loop Issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running in to an issue with making my own search loop in Wordpress. What I am trying to achieve is that certain circumstances display only certain information:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); echo '<div>'; ?>

         <?php if ( in_category('property') ) { ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_field('main-image-description'); ?>
            <span class="launch">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'boilerplate' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <span class="link">click to launch</span>
                    <span class="launch-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( in_category('all-developments') ) { ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_field('property-description'); ?>
            <span class="launch-brochure">
                <a href="<?php the_field('pdf-download-all-developments'); ?>" target="_blank">
                    <span class="link">Download Brochure</span>
                    <span class="launch-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( is_page() ) { ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <span class="launch">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'boilerplate' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <span class="link">click to launch</span>
                    <span class="launch-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </span>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php echo '</div>'; endwhile; ?>
```

The issue that arises, is that is will always render one or two empty  tags at the top and this ruins the style of it, as each div has a dotted border. Is there a way of telling Wordpress that if not of these conditions are met, then don't display the `<div>`?

Thanks in advance for any help!

JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just move the `<div>` inside the conditional statements? Like so:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php if ( in_category('property') ) { ?>
        <div> <!-- Open div here !-->
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php the_field('main-image-description'); ?>
        <span class="launch">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'boilerplate' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <span class="link">click to launch</span>
                <span class="launch-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
        </div> <!-- Close div here !-->
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ( in_category('all-developments') ) { ?>
        <div> <!-- Open div here !-->
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php the_field('property-description'); ?>
        <span class="launch-brochure">
            <a href="<?php the_field('pdf-download-all-developments'); ?>" target="_blank">
                <span class="link">Download Brochure</span>
                <span class="launch-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
        </div> <!-- Close div here !-->
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ( is_page() ) { ?>
        <div> <!-- Open div here !-->
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <span class="launch">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'boilerplate' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <span class="link">click to launch</span>
                <span class="launch-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </span>
        </div> <!-- Close div here !-->
    <?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Ryan, I think I had a wood for trees moment! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Haha, trust me, I've been there. Hope this helped you out!

Comment: @user1872510 - Don't forget that you can mark a response as the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks Ryan, you are now my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange your code so you compute the conditions before you output the content like so:

```
<?php 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    $propertyCategory        = in_category('property');
    $allDevelopmentsCategory = in_category('all-developments');
    $isPage                  = is_page();

    $output = ($propertyCategory || $allDevelopmentsCategory || $isPage);

    if($output){
        echo '<div>'; 
    }


?>

    <?php if ( $propertyCategory ) { ?>
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <?php the_field('main-image-description'); ?>
       <span class="launch">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'boilerplate' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
               <span class="link">click to launch</span>
               <span class="launch-icon"></span>
           </a>
       </span>
   <?php } ?>

   <?php if ( $allDevelopmentsCategory ) { ?>
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <?php the_field('property-description'); ?>
       <span class="launch-brochure">
           <a href="<?php the_field('pdf-download-all-developments'); ?>" target="_blank">
               <span class="link">Download Brochure</span>
               <span class="launch-icon"></span>
           </a>
       </span>
   <?php } ?>

   <?php if ( $isPage ) { ?>
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <?php the_content(); ?>
       <span class="launch">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'boilerplate' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
               <span class="link">click to launch</span>
               <span class="launch-icon"></span>
           </a>
       </span>
   <?php } ?>

   <?php 
    if($output){
        echo '</div>'; 
    }

    endwhile; 
?>
```

This allows you to detect if anything will be output and then uses a `div` where appropriate.